# Layout not updating properly in Lollipop devices with fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am facing a weird issue in my app. It is working perfectly in Android Kitkat Version but in Lollipop devices I am having a weird issue. Issue is that there is a fragment named help List and currently it is having no records therefore I just show a toast there that **No Records found**. But after this screen is opened when I open any other fragment in my app they all show no data at all, whether it is static or dynamic. Here are the screen shots to explain it more clearly

**This is the original view of this screen**
[image: This is the original view of this screen]

**And after opening that fragment that is without data, It looks like this**,[image: After image]

More over when I press the home button and then navigate back to app everything is visible again.

Here is the code for this fragment

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
    <com.bluejamesbond.text.DocumentView
        xmlns:ext="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ext:documentView_text="Doorstep Help is the most dynamic on demand service and helper application which shall make your life simple and easy. Get a servant at your door starting from Re 1/- per minute. Looking for someone to help you in shifting your house? Get a Moving Service Doorstep Helper starting at Re 3/- per minute. Want a servant for household chores like deep-cleaning, grocery buying? Get a Doorstep Household servant at your door for instant help. Need a helping hand to wash all your clothes? Get a Doorstep Laundry Helper to wash all your clothes. Your one stop solution for on-demand service and Help!"
        ext:documentView_textSize="18sp"
        ext:documentView_textAlignment="justified"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And java file just have onCreateView and nothing else so I don't think that's necessary. 
And this blank thing happens with every screen after that.
I have no clue what's causing this

I am also adding code for Help List fragment. It consists of two tabs

```
public class FragmentHelpList extends Fragment {


private ViewPager viewPager;
Context context;
public FragmentHelpList(){}





//@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_help_list, container, false);
    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabsStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new TabFragmentPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));
    // Attach the view pager to the tab strip
    tabsStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);
    return rootView;
}
```

And these are the two fragments added to view pager

**First One**

```
    public static SlidingTab1Fragment newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        SlidingTab1Fragment fragment = new SlidingTab1Fragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        appSharedPreferences= AppSharedPreferences.getsharedprefInstance(getActivity()) ;
        userid = appSharedPreferences.getUserId();
        System.out.println("allhelpstabid :  " + userid);
        ALLHELPS_URL = Baseurl + "job_working.php?customer_id="+appSharedPreferences.getUserId();

        new Loadalljobs().execute();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    }


    public void updatedisplay(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> container) {

        TabOneCustomAdapter myCustomAdapter = new TabOneCustomAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.tab1_singleitem, container);
        setListAdapter(myCustomAdapter);
        myCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.d("display execution", "");


        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                    long arg3) {
                // String value = (String) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);

                HashMap<String, String> map = AllHelpsList.get(position);

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityHelpDetailsCurrent.class);
                i.putExtra("name", map.get(TAG_NAME));
                i.putExtra("address", map.get(TAG_ADDRESS));
                i.putExtra("date", map.get(TAG_DATE));

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }



    class Loadalljobs extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading All Helps ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

            ClearListAdapter clearadapter = new ClearListAdapter();
            clearadapter.clearData();
            setListAdapter(clearadapter);

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(ALLHELPS_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);
            System.out.println("Response:" + jsonStr);
            Log.d("All Helps JSON: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            AllHelpsList.clear();
            return jsonStr;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(s);
                int status=jsonObject.getInt("status");
                if (status==1) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                        map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                        Log.d("kirti error", map + "");
                        AllHelpsList.add(map);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            updatedisplay(AllHelpsList);
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            islListViewLoaded = false;
        }
    }

   @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {


        System.out.println("Item clicked");

        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityHelpDetailsCurrent.class);
        startActivity(i);

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if(pDialog!= null)
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

**And the second fragment**

```
    public static SlidingTab2Fragment newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        SlidingTab2Fragment fragment = new SlidingTab2Fragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    // Inflate the fragment layout we defined above for this fragment
    // Set the associated text for the title
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        appSharedPreferences= AppSharedPreferences.getsharedprefInstance(getActivity()) ;

        prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        userid = appSharedPreferences.getUserId();
        System.out.println("SCHEDULED_helpstabid :  " + userid);
        SCHEDULED_URL=Baseurl+"job_scheduled.php?cid="+userid;
        System.out.println("Second tab url is: " +SCHEDULED_URL);
        new LoadScheduled().execute();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        }



    public void updatedisplay(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> container) {

        TabTwoCustomAdapter myCustomAdapter = new TabTwoCustomAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.tab2_singleitem, container);
        setListAdapter(myCustomAdapter);
        Log.d("display execution", "");

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                    long arg3) {
                // String value = (String) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);

                HashMap<String, String> map = ScheduledHelpsList.get(position);

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityHelpDetailsScheduled.class);
                i.putExtra("name", map.get(TAG_NAME));
                i.putExtra("address", map.get(TAG_ADDRESS));
                i.putExtra("time", map.get(TAG_TIME));
                i.putExtra("date",map.get(TAG_DATE));
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all OUTBOX messages by making HTTP Request
     */
    class LoadScheduled extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Scheduled Helps ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
           pDialog.show();
            ClearListAdapter clearadapter = new ClearListAdapter();
            clearadapter.clearData();
            setListAdapter(clearadapter);
        }

        /**
         * getting Outbox JSON
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
   // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(SCHEDULED_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.d("Scheduled JSON:  ", "> " + jsonStr);
            System.out.println("Response:" + jsonStr);
            ScheduledHelpsList.clear();

            try {

                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);
                    String jobtime = c.getString(TAG_DURATION);
                    String job_amount = c.getString(TAG_AMOUNT);

                    String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                    map.put(TAG_TIME, time);
                    map.put(TAG_DURATION, jobtime);
                    map.put(TAG_AMOUNT, job_amount);

                    map.put(TAG_DATE, date);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    ScheduledHelpsList.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * *
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            updatedisplay(ScheduledHelpsList);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        appSharedPreferences= AppSharedPreferences.getsharedprefInstance(getActivity()) ;
        userid = appSharedPreferences.getUserId();
        System.out.println("allhelpstabid :  " + userid);
        ALLHELPS_URL = Baseurl + "job_working.php?customer_id="+appSharedPreferences.getUserId();

        new Loadalljobs().execute();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    }


    public void updatedisplay(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> container) {

        TabOneCustomAdapter myCustomAdapter = new TabOneCustomAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.tab1_singleitem, container);
        setListAdapter(myCustomAdapter);
        myCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.d("display execution", "");


        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                    long arg3) {
                // String value = (String) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);

                HashMap<String, String> map = AllHelpsList.get(position);

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityHelpDetailsCurrent.class);
                i.putExtra("name", map.get(TAG_NAME));
                i.putExtra("address", map.get(TAG_ADDRESS));
                i.putExtra("date", map.get(TAG_DATE));

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }



    class Loadalljobs extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading All Helps ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

            ClearListAdapter clearadapter = new ClearListAdapter();
            clearadapter.clearData();
            setListAdapter(clearadapter);

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(ALLHELPS_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);
            System.out.println("Response:" + jsonStr);
            Log.d("All Helps JSON: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            AllHelpsList.clear();
            return jsonStr;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(s);
                int status=jsonObject.getInt("status");
                if (status==1) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                        map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                        Log.d("kirti error", map + "");
                        AllHelpsList.add(map);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            updatedisplay(AllHelpsList);
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            islListViewLoaded = false;
        }
    }

   @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {


        System.out.println("Item clicked");

        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityHelpDetailsCurrent.class);
        startActivity(i);

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if(pDialog!= null)
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

And this the adapter class for view pager

```
public class TabFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;

private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Current", "Scheduled"};



public TabFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment=null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return SlidingTab1Fragment.newInstance(0);
        case 1:
            return SlidingTab2Fragment.newInstance(0);
        default:
            return fragment;
    }
}



@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    return tabTitles[position];
}
```

}

Comment: Is this issue for one screen only?

Comment: after opening that blank screen this problem occurs with every screen